# Launcher utility for windows

Tags: windows, utility

I attended a conference recently. the speaker was using a utility in Mac by which a textbox appeared on center of the screen and he typed firefox to launch firefox browser. Is there any alternative for Windows Os?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you talking about `the App Directory Launcher` ? you can download it for free from below link.

http://lifehacker.com/5835770/the-best-application-launcher-for-windows